# Bootstrap datetimepicker is not a function when used within document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I have certain elements which I am adding dynamically using Jquery. 
Bootstrap Datepicker works fine on input elements that are already present on page load but doesnt work with dynamically added elements. 
So I tried using `.on` function of Jquery. But I am getting the following error when I place datepicker bind code anywhere within document ready.

**Error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
```

**Script**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').on('click', 'div[id^="datetimepicker"]', function () {
                alert();

                $('div[id^="datetimepicker"]').datetimepicker({
                    useCurrent: false 
                });

            });
        });

</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

**This doesnt work on any element (datetimepicker is not a function):**

```
   $('body').on('click', "div[id^='datetimepicker']", function () {
             console.log(this);
             $(this).datetimepicker({
                     useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
                });
        });
```

**This works only on elements that are already present:**

```
$('#griddt').find('div[id^="datetimepicker"]').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
    });
```

**UPDATE 2:** 
(click inside the first textbox to add new row of grid, click inside second to see the calendar - which works only within first row)
https://jsfiddle.net/a8j30rcw/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to listen on datetime picker based on an `id` attribute at all. 
 The reason is that adding elements dynamically inside the page may create more than one occurrences of the datetime picker w

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-group').html(`<div class='datetimepicker input-group date'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>`);
});


$('body').on('click', '.datetimepicker', function() {
  var tp = $(this);
  if (tp.data().DateTimePicker) {
    return true;
  }
  tp.datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false
  });
  tp.data().DateTimePicker.show();
});
```

```css
/* Optional theme */

@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
@import url(https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css')
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ith the same `id`. Yet again `id` **has** to be unique.

Use a class (`datetimepicker`) or some HTML `data-attribute` then listen for it. Since the event handles dynamic elements added after page load you don't actually need `$(document).ready` at all although you may add it without any side effects.

```
    $('body').on('click', '.datetimepicker', function(){
        var tp = $(this);
        if (tp.data().DateTimePicker) {
            return true;
        }
        tp.datetimepicker({useCurrent: false});
        tp.data().DateTimePicker.show();
    });
```

Update: 
On `click` you just initialized the picker everytime a click occurs. Never triggered the `show` method. I check if time-picker is initialized during the first click if not, I initialize it and showing the picker. In any other case I leave timepicker code to do its job by returning early.

Update: [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/a8j30rcw/)

Comment: it looks like datetimepicker function is not available when its within any event. Such as 'click' . But if I write       `$('.input-group.date').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });` outside document.ready , outside any event. It works for already present elements.

Comment: Updated. Please see above.

Comment: nope no luck. tp datetimepicker is not a function : (

Comment: if that's what it says means you haven't loaded bootstrap in your html - So probably wrap this in a `$(document).ready()`. I am telling this since `tp.datetimepicker` is the same as `$(this).datetimepicker` which should work.

Comment: added JSFiddle example in the above answer [https://jsfiddle.net/a8j30rcw/](https://jsfiddle.net/a8j30rcw/)

Comment: Although your fiddle is working fine, I am still unable to make my code work. It makes no sense.   `.DateTimePicker`works fine inside click event in your fiddle. But it just dosnt when I put it inside click event. It ONLY recognizes .DateTimePicker event when its called outside `ready` and outside any `.on` methods

Comment: I have created a fiddle for you that would help you understand exactly what i am facing 
https://jsfiddle.net/a8j30rcw/1/

Comment: I figured out the problem. The problem was that the MVC was rendering two head tags. One from layout page another was on my page. Who could have thought. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Whereever you are calling datepicker function use like this:-

```
$('body').on('click',"#datetimepicker", function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker();
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 possibilities

1: either datetimepicker  script is not loaded yet,

2: datetimepicker id isn't available to jquery

for both above case you can try timeout just to see if this is the issue

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

// call to datepicker 
    $('div[id^="datetimepicker"]').datetimepicker({
           useCurrent: false 
    });

 }, 200);
```

if this doesnt work it means you have duplicate ids. instead of id use class to refer to your element

```
$('.datepickerclass').datetimepicker({
           useCurrent: false 
    });
```

Comment: id is always unique and can't have multiple ids it exist will take first id .. try using class instead of id ....

Comment: Tried it with class. Same issue.

Comment: it looks like datetimepicker function is not available when its within any event. Such as 'click' . But if I write       `$('.input-group.date').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });` outside document.ready , outside any event. It works for already present elements.